# Mongodb select with condition is selected result must in sub select query

Tags: mongodb

How do you do nested select in MongoDB analogous to

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not yet possess the ability to do subqueries which would allow this functionality.

I am sure it is something within the JIRA however, I could not immediately find it.

The only way currently is to actually pick the table, iterate the cursor pulling out the information and using that as part of a `$in` query as shown by @Bruno, like so:

```
ids=[];
for(i in db.c2.find({},{_id:1}){ // I have assumed id=_id
    ids[ids.length]=i; // The default return of the index pos is actually _id
}
return db.c1.find({$in:ids});
```

As a mere example I wrote off of the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

This page contains comparator between SQL and MongoDB:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

For example, you can to use a aggregation pipeline and where is the same as:

```
db.your_collection.aggregate({$match: {"id": {$in: ['id_0', 'id_1']} }})
```

A simple query as the same as:

```
db.your_collection.aggregate({field: "value"})
```

Mongodb official page has a lot of informations

Comment: Why would you use aggregation for this?

Comment: ({$match: {"id": {$in: ['id_0', 'id_1']} }}) is not same with "IN (SELECT id FROM table2)"